# Best way to remove characters from string in c# win. form

Tags: c#, string, performance

i have a string of **length 98975333** and i need to **remove first 5 letters** in it. Can anyone suggest the **best way to do this keeping performance in mind**?

I tried

```
 str.Substring(5,str.Length);
 str.Remove(0,5);
```

which gives me **result in 0.29 sec**
but i want something even faster than the above.

**Problem Using StringBuilder**

-> i need to substring a part of the string and to do this i need to write

```
 StringBuilder2.ToString().Substring(anyvaluehere)"
```

here the conversion of StringBuilder to string by ".ToString()" takes time and in this case i cant use StringBuilder

Comment: That code doesn't actually do anything useful because it doesn't do anything with the results.  You say "remove", which implies that you want to end up with one new `string` that contains all the original characters except the first five.  Is that correct, or do you actually mean "separate", implying that you want two new `string` objects, one containing the first five characters and one containing the rest?

Comment: Just want to point out that if you have a string that's 98MB big, you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: first of all 98MB big string in my case is right and i want to remove the first 5 letters and want it back in the string or you can say new string.

Comment: The actual string is probably around 189MB in size as Unicode uses two bytes per character. Yes, something is probably wrong. I bet building this string is far more time consuming that the 0.29 seconds it takes to remove the first 5 characters. I think you're barking up the wrong tree here.

Comment: yes sir you are right building string took a lot of time but here what i am asking is to remove first 5 letters from my string

Comment: Do you need to output the string before this part? Can't you first use StringBuilder and do the .Remove() function?

Comment: @Tyress got a problem that any time i need to use the StringBuilder to substring i need to convert it into toString() and it takes even more time than before, but the removeing part was fast

Comment: Where does the string come from? I guess you can solve the problem (removing chars) while *reading* the string. If it is read from a file, I would suggest to read it line by line (`File.ReadAllLines`), so you have to manipulate only the first line. If it's from a stream, I would manipulate it while reading from stream.

Comment: first of all the content is not coming from a file and is some encrypted text and cant remove chars as removing char will make it impossible to decrypt it.

Comment: But you want do remove the first 5 chars?

Comment: yes sir, but to use substring i need to convert stringbuilder to string which makes my performance low.

Comment: StringBuilder also have a [`Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.remove%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the .Net [encryption methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.icryptotransform.transformblock%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) always uses a byte array for encryption/decryption as input. And they allows to use a offset, so here you can skip the first 5 chars. Maybe you can use a `byte[]` ?

Comment: i converted byte[] to string on purpose to manipulate the bytes in a specific format.

Comment: I you use [`Encoding.GetString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05cts4c3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for that, you can specify a starting index to skip the first 5 chars?

Comment: no sir after manipulating i needed to remove 5 string which i have achieved but thank you sir for all your precious time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a StringBuilder to produce and manipulate the string will help you save on resources:

```
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.Append("text"); //to add text in front

    sb.Insert(50,"text"); // to insert text

    sb.Remove(50,4); // to remove text

    sb.ToString(); // to produce the string
```

If you have a fixed length of string that you wish to store elsewhere, you can make a char array and use StringBuilder's CopyTo() method:

e.g.

```
    char[] firstfive = new char[5];
    sb.CopyTo(0,firstfive,0,5);
```

Edit:

Actually, the OP figured this out himself, but I'm including it on the post for reference:

To get a portion of the StringBuilder as string:

```
sb.ToString(intStart,intLength)
```

Comment: sir conversion of "98975333" length to string takes time and is not a feasible way to do it and to substring "StringBuilder1.ToString()" is necessary

Comment: You would have to work around making it a string at any point in between. The CopyTo method doesn't require you to do a ToString().

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, c# strings are not arrays; they are [immutable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx) so extracting a (possibly very long) substring involves a copy.

However, most [string utilities] accept start and end indices, for instance [`IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`CompareInfo.Compare`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebe1220%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) all take a `startIndex`overload.

Perhaps if you tell us what you want to do afterward we could suggest alternatives?

**Update**

Here are some ways you can write performant string parsing with the immutable strings in c#.  Say for instance that you need to deserialize XML data inside the string, and need to skip the first N characters.  You could do something like this:

```
    public static object XmlDeserializeFromString<T>(this string objectData, int skip)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        using (var reader = new StringReader(objectData))
        {
            for (; skip > 0 && reader.Read() != -1; skip--)
                ;
            return (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
```

As you can see from [the source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/stringreader.cs). `StringReader.Read()` does not make a copy of the unread portion of the string, it keeps an internal index to the remaining unread portion.

Or say you want to skip the first N characters of a string, then parse the string by splitting it at every "," character.  You could write something like this:

```
    public static IEnumerable<Pair<int>> WalkSplits(this string str, int startIndex, int count, params char[] separator)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
            yield break;
        var length = str.Length;
        int endIndex;
        if (count < 0)
            endIndex = length;
        else
        {
            endIndex = startIndex + count;
            if (endIndex > length)
                endIndex = length;
        }

        while (true)
        {
            int nextIndex = str.IndexOfAny(separator, startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
            if (nextIndex == startIndex)
            {
                startIndex = nextIndex + 1;
            }
            else if (nextIndex == -1)
            {
                if (startIndex < endIndex)
                    yield return new Pair<int>(startIndex, endIndex - 1);
                yield break;
            }
            else
            {
                yield return new Pair<int>(startIndex, nextIndex - 1);
                startIndex = nextIndex + 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

And then use the start and end indices of the `Pair` to further parse the string, or extract small substrings to feed to further parsing methods.

(`Pair<T>` is a small struct I created similar to [`KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but with identically typed first and second values.  I can provide if needed.)

Comment: you are right but keeping performance in mind i cant use "indexof" it takes the same or even more time than the above mentioned codes

Comment: `subString.Indexof(c)` is not going to be faster than [`str.Indexof(c, 6)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xkyx09y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with long strings, always use StringBuilder. This class provides you fast adding and removing characters, faster than String.Concat or it's syntactic sugar "a" + "b". Moreover StringBuilder.ToString() method has special implementation for best performance as possible.

Comment: Don't just use `StringBuilder` for long strings. Use it for what it is designed for: *manipulating* strings. If you have a long string that you never change or modify, there's no point in using StringBuilder.

Answer (score -1):

Use `String.Remove()` i.e

```
String newStr = "";
newStr = str.Remove(0,5); //This will delete 5 characters starting from 0 index
```

Or

```
newStr = str.Remove(5); //Assumes the starting position as 0 and will ddelete 5 chars from that
```

Read more [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxbw3kwc(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: If strings were *mutable*, you'd intuitively suspect that this is faster. But since either way, you're creating a new string for the return value, it isn't obvious that it will be faster. Did you measure it?

Comment: The removal of chars would be faster in `Remove()` case. And yes they can always use the same String for storing the returned value. If this improves performance.

Comment: On the inside, `string.Remove()` just does an allocation + wstrcpy().  Source: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs

Comment: No, it *cannot* use the same string. `String` is an *immutable* class. You don't have to dig into the source code; it is *documented* that way.

Comment: sir the solution you wrote was already written in my question any other method than i provided?

Comment: @Agent_Spock if you want to remove 5 letters and store the result in another string, why don't you use Remove()?